# alert with src attribute of any element i click with jQuery or Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
<img src="pic1.jpg" class="mythumbs">
<img src="pic2.jpg" class="mythumbs">
<img src="pic3.jpg" class="mythumbs">
<img src="pic4.jpg" class="mythumbs">

<script>
/*
here is the code which makes me when i click on any image, it shows me its src attribute
(without using idTag 'preferred'). 
*/

alert(theAttribute);
</script>
```

i need to type a code which shows me the clicked item's src attribute without using idTags

Answer (score 4):

```
$(function(){
  $("img.mythumbs").click(function(){
    alert($(this).attr("src"));    
  });
});
```

This code will alert the src attribute of all `img` elements which has a css class `mythumbs`

Working sample : http://jsfiddle.net/tZcpw/1/

Comment: `alert(this.src);` no need to always use jQuery

Comment: @F.Calderan: Yea. But i like to write Unobutrusive javascript. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unobtrusive_JavaScript . So that my beahviour is seperated from presentation

Comment: it's not a matter of unobtrusive js: just don't call `$` function whenever you don't really need to.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution without `ID` and `Class`. This will alert `src` when you click images.

```
$("img").click(function(){
    alert($(this).attr("src"));    
});
```

You may replace `$("img")` with `$(".your_class-here")` if you want to do this with a class.

***[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/blasteralfred/Ef5t2/)*** is a working Live Demo.